# Displaying tooltips in PyQT for a QTreeView item

Tags: pyqt, tooltip

I have followed some useful online tutorials by Yasin Uludag to experiment with PyQt (or rather PySide) to create a simple tree view, but I'm having problems with getting tooltips to work. In the following code, the tooltip text is displayed on the console rather than in a tooltip window. All the other examples I have seen use setToolTip directly on the widget item, but I don't think I have direct access to that in this Model/View approach. Is there some initialization I need to do on the QTreeView itself?

```
 class TreeModel(QtCore.QAbstractItemModel):

     def __init__(self, root, parent=None):
         super(NXTreeModel, self).__init__(parent)
         self._rootNode = root

     def data(self, index, role):

          node = index.internalPointer()

         if role == QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole or role == QtCore.Qt.EditRole:
             return node.name()

         if role == QtCore.Qt.ToolTipRole:
             return node.keys()
```

Answer (score 6):

It worked like below code.

```
class TreeModel(QAbstractItemModel):
    ...
    def data(self, index, role=Qt.DisplayRole):
        ...
        if role == Qt.ToolTipRole:
            return 'ToolTip'

    def flags(self, index):
        if not index.isValid():
            return Qt.NoItemFlags # 0
        return Qt.ItemIsSelectable # or Qt.ItemIsEnabled
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to enable the ToolTip role

```
class TreeModel(QtCore.QAbstractItemModel):
    ...

    def flags(self, index):
        if not index.isValid():
            return 0
        return QtCore.Qt.ItemIsEditable | QtCore.Qt.ItemIsEnabled |\
               QtCore.Qt.ItemIsSelectable | QtCore.Qt.ToolTip
```

Comment: Qt::ToolTip is not a flag in Qt, so this won't work. Use the data function instead and return something useful for the Qt::ToolTipRole.