# QTableView to show the content of table item when mouse hover

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, qtableview

Writing with phone, so the format may be bad.

I have a table with `QTableView`, there are two columns in the table. The second column contains a very long string which can't be fully shown without resizing. I want to show the string in a rectangle when I hover the mouse on one item, and the rectangle is near the mouse (many software like Eclipse and VS have such function).

I have searched the internet for a while, but still don't know how to program this view feature.

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First to implement the popup you need to know when the mouse enters the region of an item in the table, for this we will use the `eventFilter()` method and will look for when the `QEvent::MouseMove` event is used and we will obtain the index through the function `indexAt()` and the position of the mouse, and compare if this is different from the previous index. And if it happens it will show or hide the popup as needed.

To create the PopUp we use a dialog and insert a QLabel, and use the setWordWrap property to fit the text correctly

```
#ifndef TABLEVIEW_H
#define TABLEVIEW_H

#include <QDialog>
#include <QEvent>
#include <QLabel>
#include <QMouseEvent>
#include <QTableView>
#include <QVBoxLayout>
#include <QHeaderView>

class TableView: public QTableView{
    Q_OBJECT
    QDialog *popup;
    QLabel *popupLabel;

public:
    TableView(QWidget *parent = Q_NULLPTR):QTableView(parent){
        viewport()->installEventFilter(this);
        setMouseTracking(true);
        popup = new QDialog(this, Qt::Popup | Qt::ToolTip);

        QVBoxLayout *layout = new QVBoxLayout;
        popupLabel = new QLabel(popup);
        popupLabel->setWordWrap(true);
        layout->addWidget(popupLabel);
        popupLabel->setTextFormat(Qt::RichText);
        //popupLabel->setOpenExternalLinks(true);
        popup->setLayout(layout);
        popup->installEventFilter(this);
    }

    bool eventFilter(QObject *watched, QEvent *event){
        if(viewport() == watched){
            if(event->type() == QEvent::MouseMove){
                QMouseEvent *mouseEvent = static_cast<QMouseEvent*>(event);
                QModelIndex index = indexAt(mouseEvent->pos());
                if(index.isValid()){
                    showPopup(index);
                }
                else{
                    popup->hide();
                }
            }
            else if(event->type() == QEvent::Leave){
                popup->hide();
            }
        }
        else if(popup == watched){
            if(event->type() == QEvent::Leave){
                popup->hide();
            }
        }
        return QTableView::eventFilter(watched, event);
    }

private:
    void showPopup (const QModelIndex &index) const {
        if(index.column() == 1){
            QRect r = visualRect(index);
            popup->move(viewport()->mapToGlobal(r.bottomLeft()));
            popup->setFixedSize(100, popup->heightForWidth(100));
            popupLabel->setText(index.data(Qt::DisplayRole).toString());
            popup->adjustSize();
            popup->show();
        }
        else {
            popup->hide();
        }
    }
};

#endif // TABLEVIEW_H
```

**Screenshot:**

[image]

In the following link you will find an [example](https://github.com/eyllanesc/stackoverflow/tree/master/46431491-qtableview-show-the-content-of-table-item-when-mouse-hover).

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion or drawn-out debugging sessions; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/155418/discussion-on-answer-by-eyllanesc-qtableview-show-the-content-of-table-item-when). If more information needs to be added, it should be edited into the question or answer, as applicable.

Comment: Not yet. The scroll bar does't show in my project. In your link project, the scroll bar shows but it does't work well.  Besides, the popup still does't show multi-lines. Good news is that the popup disappear correctly.

Comment: I suddenly realized that you perhaps misunderstand the scroll bar. I hope I can drag the scroll to show the full content of my second column. As your image shows, your scroll bar does't show all contents of your second column.

Comment: I have tried to paint an image but failed, I show it with a gvim screenshot. I am not clear what you mean "spearating the word", but I think you can arbitrary separate it.

Comment: The query is only a line-number (Address), does't need a dash

Comment: The query is only related to the memory view, it does't influence the table.Perhaps you refer to the popup, the popup really shows 8 Hex characters separated by dashes.

Comment: Year, it' s a good choice. The problem is that the 00000000 00000000 will be hard to clarify in the table item. Is there someway to show 0000000-0000000 in  table and show 00000000 0000000 in popup. Or if " : " or other separator works.

Comment: I have tried "_" ":", they both don't work, but I can process the word in `   popupLabel->setText(index.data(Qt::DisplayRole).toString());` to convert the separator with `blank`, so this problem is solved, hah. The last problem about the popup, is there some other way?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/155471/discussion-between-eyllanesc-and-noodles-guo).

Answer (score 16):

Damn.  Everybody has to try to do it the hard way, and start subclassing stuff and reinventing stuff that doesn't need it.  The answer is already in [Displaying tooltips in PyQT for a QTreeView item](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8682586/displaying-tooltips-in-pyqt-for-a-qtreeview-item)

The answer, is that in the data() function of yer model, just return something useful when called for 'Qt::ToolTipRole;' after first checking 'index.column()' to make sure it is the right column.

Here's some similar foolishness:

[Show tooltips for long entries of your custom model](https://wiki.qt.io/Show_tooltips_for_long_entries_of_your_custom_model)

I'll give them the benefit of a doubt, and assume that Qt used to work that way; but it doesn't now.  They have people making this custom event filter; whereas I returned a tooltip for the ToolTipRole for a given column in a model of mine, and the tooltips only showed up for cells in the column that values were returned for.  This is simply unnecessary work, it is not needed now, and it wastes time.  This wiki entry is very likely, simply out of date.